# Many 'feature selection' in the same dataset

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, feature-selection, unsupervised-learning

If I have, for example, a dataset with 30 variables, 25 numerical and 5 categorical. I need to explain (predict) 3 categorical variables and 2 numerical variables from that dataset (let's call it "target") with the following considerations:

1. Some variables only explain the "target 1" and others explain the
   "target 2" respectively.
2. It may be that a variable explains "target 1" and "target 3".
3. It may be that a target explains another target.
4. Predictive variables can only be numeric. In contrast the targets
   (variable to be predicted) can be numerical or categorical.

I have tried to address the problem by having five completely equal sets of data, setting a target respectively and deleting the categorical variables (except the target) and applying a feature selection in each case separately.

My question are:

- Is it an appropriate approach?
- Is it correct that a target in a case can be an independent variable in another case?
- Can this be done in an unsupervised way? That is: Automatic model selection
- Is it correct to eliminate categorical variables when they are not targets in a given case?

Observation: Categorical data are coded before entering the analysis and I will try to apply different learning methods. From regressions to classification.

Comment: One question to ask in such analysis is ... are targets correlated? In the real-world are other targets available when predicting a target? If yes you can use them.

Comment: It is for analysis in chemometrics. Some targets may be correlated. But predicting different targets as "a separate case" pursues different goals. A target in a separate case may not serve much to predict others, but sometimes it does influence the prediction of other targets. This has its theoretical basis in chemistry.

Comment: Summarizing everything in two questions: Is there a feature selection method that discards variables based on a target (the most important variable) for the same data set? Or will I always get the same "releveant features" regardless of who the target is?
(*Excuse me for my poor english-language)

Comment: feature selection is always supervised. It will select different features given different target for the same data. Generally, you can have only one target. If that target changes then the feature selection should select different features depending upon the data.

Comment: Using any Feature Selection algorithm?

Comment: *ANY but in theory; and also depends upon data but ... If two targets are different (not mutually exclusive of course), feature selection algorithm should select different features.

Comment: So apparently my question already has an answer. I am planning to use "Randomized sparse models" of the "Scikit-Learn" module to generate a ranking of "features" that are important for each target. I would have to see the empirical results.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Great! Please do share the findings from empirical results.